# Do critical shots affect legendary effects?

Tags: fallout-4

For example, I have a combat rifle with the 'Explosive' effect, i.e. it lets projectiles explode on impact, dealing additional damage.

If I use a critical shot, does that affect just the base ballistic damage of the bullet, or would it affect the additional explosive damage as well?

Comment: To be honest, the exact calculation is boosted by a lot of things.  Perks that affect the gun, perks that affect explosion (100% tested Explosive perk affects the radius of the explosive shot).  I have an Explosive Mini Gun and one VATS shot (10 rounds, non-critical) will kill a Mythical Death Claw or a Deathskull Radscorpion.

Before I had maxed Adamantium Skeleton, I would easily cripple multiple limbs if I was in the same room as my target.  But it's a very fun weapon.

Answer (score 2):

Critical Shots boost everything, Perk Power, Effects, and even base damage. That means that you will get pretty much damage from Critical shots.

Answer (score -1):

Im pretty sure a critical shot is just that, regardless of the legendary effect eg: ive used two weapons identical same kill one i put legendary effect on the other not and both states resulted the same except the explosive effect looked good and with bloody mess perk cool too.

Answer (score -3):

I would think that the critical would affect the explosion as well. Usually a critical shot boosts all stats on that ammunition.